# Prolog, program to determine if two lists are not equal

Tags: prolog

I want to build a Prolog program to determine if two lists, provided as arguments, are not equal.

This is what I did so far.

```
not-equal([],[a|_]).
not-equal([a|_],[H|T]):-not-equal(a,T).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prolog lists are just terms that can be "compared" directly using the equality operators. *Not equal* can mean *not unifiable* or *not identical*.

*not unifiable*

```
?- [1, 2] \= [1, 2].        ===> false
?- [1, 2] \= [1, X].        ===> false
?- [1, 2] \= [1, 3].        ===> true
```

*not identical*

```
?- [1, 2] \== [1, 2].        ===> false
?- [1, 2] \== [1, X].        ===> true
?- [1, 2] \== [1, 3].        ===> true
```

Comment: `dif/2` is a sound option: `?- dif([1,2],[1,X]). ===> dif(X, 2).`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
not-equal([],[H|_]).
not-equal([H|_],[]).
not-equal([H|T1],[H|T2]) :-
    not-equal(T1,T2).

not-equal([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
    not(var(H1)),
    not(var(H2)),
    H1 =\= H2.
```

In your predicates you have a lowercase 'a' which is an atom and not a variable. Also when you call `not-equal(a,T)` you are going outside of using lists so it's not going to work.

I'd also consider changing the name of the predicate to `not-unifiable` as the the list may contain variables that could make them equal or not depending on how those variables are unified in the future.

There are still cases that don't work with my above code.

As an alternative I would consider using the `?=` operator instead, like this:

```
not-equal([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :- not([H1|T1]?=[H2|T2]).
```

Let me know if these help.

Comment: Please note that `not-equal(X,Y)` is a term with principal functor `(-)/2`. Use `not_equal(X,Y)` instead. As for `(?=)/2`, this succeeds for idential *and* nonunifyable terms. So you fail for `not_equal([X],[Y]).`